# Deserializaing EnumMap using jackson

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, enum-map

I've added the `@JsonAnySetter` annotation to `addProperty` method

```
Map<MyEnum, String> mymap = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);

@JsonAnySetter
public void addProperty(MyEnum key, Object value) {
    mymap.put(key, value);
}
```

but while deserializing I'm getting the below error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid
>   'any-setter' annotation on method 'addProperty()': first argument not
>   of type String or Object, but java.lang.Enum

If I change the map to simple HashMap with key of type String then it works fine.

Could someone please let me know what nneds to be done for deserializing to EnumMap

Comment: Could you please show an example json string you are trying to deserialze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@JsonAnySetter` annotation seems to work only with the `String` or `Object` key types.

The workaround I found is to overload the `addProperty` method with the key type as String, then convert the String key to Enum type and call the `addProperty` method with Enum key.

Use the `@JsonAnySetter` annotation on the overloaded method.

```
Map<MyEnum, String> mymap = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);

public void addProperty(MyEnum key, Object value) {
    mymap.put(key, value);
}

@JsonAnySetter
private void addProperty(String key, Object value) {
    addProperty(MyEnum.valueOf(key), value);
}
```

Note that I've made the overloaded `addProperty` method **`private`** as I don't want to expose this method version.

`@JsonAnySetter` annotation seems to work with `private` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that:

First argument is the name of property ,so it must be String.

You can convert it to Enum in your set method.